# Node-Fetch unhandled promise rejection (can't catch it)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, node-fetch

I'm struggling for 2 days on this one so I try asking here:

I have a nodejs script using node-fetch to make queries ton an API. However, I've tried adding catch blocks everywhere but it seems I didn't suceeded in ahndling the error.

Here is my function:

```
fetchUrl.get = async (url, params = false, headers = false) => {
        let defaultOptions = {
            method: "GET",
        };
    
        let finalUrl = new URL(url);
        Object.keys(params).forEach((key) =>
            finalUrl.searchParams.append(key, params[key])
        );
    
        let finalHeaders = {};
    
        if (headers != null && headers != false && Object.keys(headers).length > 0) {
            Object.keys(headers).forEach((headerKey) => {
                finalHeaders[headerKey] = headers[headerKey];
            });
        }
    
        defaultOptions["headers"] = finalHeaders;
    
        let result = null;
    
        try {
            result = await fetch(finalUrl, defaultOptions)
                .then((res) => {
                    if (res.status == 200) {
                        return {
                            success: true,
                            text: res.text(),
                        };
                    } else {
                        console.log("ERROR during Fetch: " + res.status);
                        console.error(finalUrl);
                        console.error(params);
                        res.text().then((err) => {
                            console.error(err);
                        });
                        return {
                            success: false,
                        };
                    }
                })
                .then((resParsed) => {
                    if (resParsed.success) {
                        return resParsed.text;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
        } catch (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    
        return result;
    };
```

And this is the error I get:

```
(node:2272) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: request to http://gdsfdfs.com/ failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND gdsfdfs.com
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (file:///home/kashnars/pearlv2/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:108:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:375:28)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:475:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:375:28)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
(node:2272) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 50)
```

I know the URL is wrong, it's just for testing purposes. I need to catch the error.

Someone having the solution?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Since the function you've shown throws an error, if the caller doesn't handle it, you'll end up with an unhandled promise rejection

Comment: Apart from that obvious defect (`throw err`), you also are not handling rejections on the `res.text()` promise anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you throw an error, which is a Promise rejection in an async function

The calling function needs to handle the rejection

Now, since all you do in the `catch` is rethrow the error, no need to use try/catch at all

More simplifiction of your code is possible - but, basically, from the `await` it should go like

```
const res = await fetch(finalUrl, defaultOptions);
if (res.status == 200) {
    return res.text();
}
console.log("ERROR during Fetch: " + res.status);
console.log(finalUrl);
console.log(params);
const err = await res.text();
console.error(err);
return false;
```

with no try/catch

Alternatively, if you want this function to handle the network error, and return false, just like when status !== 200

```
try {
    const res = await fetch(finalUrl, defaultOptions);
    if (res.status == 200) {
        return res.text();
    }
    console.log("ERROR during Fetch: " + res.status);
    console.log(finalUrl);
    console.log(params);
    const err = await res.text();
    throw err;
} catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
    return false;
}
```

as a bonus, the code above the `try {` or `await fetch` can be simplified to

```
fetchUrl.get = async (url, params = false, headers = false) => {
    const defaultOptions = { 
        method: "GET",
        headers: {...(headers ?? {}) }
    };
    
    const finalUrl = new URL(url);
    Object.entries(params ?? {}).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        finalUrl.searchParams.append(key, value)
    });
```